# Xcode 6: 'Answers.h' file not found after Fabric Crashlytics update

Tags: ios, xcode6, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I was working along in my storyboard in Xcode 6.3.2 on an Objective-C project.  All of a sudden when I try to build I get an error:

/.../Developer/ProjectName/Crashlytics.framework/Headers/Crashlytics.h:14:9: 'Answers.h' file not found

I've had Crashlytics installed and working in my app for a few weeks.  I have it running through the Fabric plugin.  I switched over the the Fabric app and noticed it had recently updated Crashlytics.

In Xcode if I go "Source Control" -> "Commit..." to look at my changes, it only shows the changes I made - which are unrelated to Crashlytics.

Is anyone else seeing this?  Anyone have suggestions on the most efficient way to recover and get back to work?

I'm just a bit frustrated having no control when a dependency updates.

**UPDATE:**

To get the project to a build-able state so that I can keep working, I temporarily removed the following lines from my AppDelegate:

- `#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>`
- `[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];`

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. This sounds like something weird happened during the upgrade process. If you right-click on the Crashlytics and Fabric frameworks in your project, select "Show in Finder", and open the info.plist, what's the version value in "Bundle versions string, short"?

Comment: Thanks @Alexizamerican for reaching out.  I ended up talking to support via the "Contact support" link at http://support.crashlytics.com/. I've since completely removed Crashlytics from the project and reinstalled -- this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up reaching support via the "Contact support" link at http://support.crashlytics.com/.

They provided me some steps to remove the old Crashlytics framework from my project and then reinstall it manually.  It wasn't clear to me that he intended that I remove the framework via Finder instead of Xcode, so my attempt to follow the instructions resulted in a number of side affects (eg framework ended up in the wrong directory, I had a nameless folder on my desktop from a ditto command he had me run...this caused Time Machine to mysteriously stop working until I deleted the folder).

I ended up completely removing Fabric and Crashlytics from the project, and then I used the Fabric OSX app to install Crashlytics back into the project.  From here the project was working again.

To remove Crashlytics and Fabric from the project, I did the following:

1. Deleted Crashlytics.framework and Fabric.framework from my project via Xcode
2. Deleted the run script in Project properties -> Build Phases.  This may be optional.  It's important to verify though that the unique id in the run script matches what Fabric provides upon reinstall.
3. Deleted the following 3 lines in the AppDelegate.  This may be optional.  It will need to be replaced upon reinstall.

   ```
   #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
   #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

   [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
   ```

Comment: For anyone else reading this - I think the real trick is either #2 or #3 above, probably #3. I was stuck on the build-to-continue phase and the existence of either #2 or #3's stuff in the project files confused the Fabric app.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I was following the Fabric.app's steps which told me to include `#import <Answers/Answers.h>` but all I needed was:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

...

[Answers logCustomEventWithName:@"My First Custom Event"
                  customAttributes:@{}];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Crashlytics+Answer try this:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h> //Obj-C
import Crashlytics                  //Swift
```