# Fabric/Crashlytics: 'ANSCompatibility.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After 2 months of work having Fabric/Crashlytics integrated into a project all of a sudden after the next build I got:

> .../Crashlytics.framework/Headers/Answers.h:9:9: 'ANSCompatibility.h' file not found

There are no Crashlytics-related code changes had been made since the last successful build so I make a conclusion that it somehow has to do with the last automatic Fabric update (2.0.5).

I even can't provide any logs by setting:

```
[Crashlytics sharedInstance].debugMode = YES
```

Because of the error occurs on the compiling phase.

I found the similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994561/xcode-6-answers-h-file-not-found-after-fabric-crashlytics-update). And the author resolved the issue by reinstalling the framework. But it is not an acceptable way in my case because Crashlytics quite deeply integrated into the project and it would be quite painful to do that. In addition I need to understand why this happens and how to solve it in the future if it has place to be - it's not a solution to do reinstalling after the each update.

Used software: El Capitan 10.11.1 / Xcode 7.1.1 / Fabric 2.0.5 / Crashlytics 3.4.0

Have someone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem has been solved by copying missing headers and binaries from `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework` folders of another project (it turned out a couple more files were missed).

And it seems it is not the problem on the Fabric side and it is just my inattention as it has been mentioned in the comments on this answer thanks to @trojanfoe.

But anyway I hope it may help someone to detect similar inattention in the future.

Comment: Do you use `git` (or equivalent)?

Comment: Sure, I use `git` just wanted not to be tied to the particular version control system.

Comment: So is it possible the new files were missed from being managed by git?

Comment: I checked the last commit where Crashlytics was updated to the last version (3.4.0) 10 days ago and indeed there are no such files in that commit. In all likelihood I really didn't commit some files and after some `git reset` I had encountered the problem. Thanks for sending into the right direction - I will edit my answer.